powershell get-aduser syntax
I have been struggling with some syntax error using powershell.  Wondering if a kind soul may shed some light on my issue.
    $userDataRows = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter '(&(objectClass=User)(objectCategory=Person))' |     Select-Object -Property  
    @{N='AcctName';E={$_.'cn'}}
    ,@{N='Name';E={$_.'name'}}
    ,@{N='FirstName';E={$_.'givenName'}}
    ,@{N='Initial';E={$_.'initials'}}
    ,@{N='LastName';E={$_.'sn'}}
    ,@{N='MyID';E={$_.'extensionAttribute6'}}
    ,@{N='Badge';E={$_.'extensionAttribute2'}}
    ,@{N='Address';E={$_.'streetaddress'}}
    ,@{N='City';E={$_.'l'}}
    ,@{N='State';E={$_.'st'}}
    ,@{N='Office';E={$_.'physicalDeliveryOfficeName'}}
    ,@{N='Country';E={$_.'co'}}
    ,@{N='CountryID';E={$_.'c'}}
    ,@{N='PostCode';E={$_.'postalCode'}}
    ,@{N='Phone';E={$_.'telephoneNumber'}}


does not extract the data I need.
Instead, I received the error:
Select-Object : Missing an argument for parameter 'Property'. Specify a parameter of type
'System.Object[]' and try again.
At line:1 char:65

My general issue is I am hoping to extract several fields of data from AD.  Its when I try to rename that I seem to be going off track.  I have searched can't seem to figure what I'm doing wrong.   Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance!
Jeff

PowerShell tentatively considers newline characters statement terminators if the preceding statement is syntactically complete.
From a syntax perspective, Get-ADUser ... |Select-Object -Property is a complete statement, so when PowerShell encounters the line break after -Property it automatically goes "this must be the end of this pipeline statement", and the arguments on the following lines are not interpreted as part of it.
This behavior also affects the following lines, since you've moved the , array item separator down on the next line - so PowerShell sees 1 pipeline statement (ending with the token -Property), followed by a line with a single hashtable literal, followed by 14 lines of self-contained array literals.
Remove the line break between -Property and the first argument token, then for each line break in the argument list move the , up on the preceding line - this will then force the parser to continue parsing the statement on the next line until it reaches the last argument:
$userDataRows = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter '(&(objectClass=User)(objectCategory=Person))' |Select-Object -Property @{N='AcctName';E='cn'},
    Name,
    @{N='FirstName';E='givenName'},
    @{N='Initial';E='initials'},
    @{N='LastName';E='sn'},
    @{N='MyID';E='extensionAttribute6'},
    @{N='Badge';E='extensionAttribute2'},
    @{N='Address';E='streetaddress'},
    @{N='City';E='l'},
    @{N='State';E='st'},
    @{N='Office';E='physicalDeliveryOfficeName'},
    @{N='Country';E='co'},
    @{N='CountryID';E='c'},
    @{N='PostCode';E='postalCode'},
    @{N='Phone';E='telephoneNumber'}

Note: you don't need to supply a scriptblock as the Expression parameter when simply renaming properties - @{Name='NewName';Expression={$_.'OldName'}} can be expressed as @{Name='NewName';Expression='OldName'}

isnt (&(objectClass=User)(objectCategory=Person)) redundant in this case? this is already the default filter for Get-ADUser iirc

@SantiagoSquarzon Yup, completely superfluous, and indeed identical to the object filter used by the object factory Get-ADUser uses internally anyways :)
